# excel: comparing the value of two cells, and set the value in another cell

Tags: excel, compare

In excel i want two compare two values, *Artikelcode(sheet1)*  and *sku(sheet2)*
when these values are the same then it should look at *Vooraadstatus(sheet1)* if this is "End of Life" then it should change the value of *status(sheet2)* to 0

[image: sheet1]

[image: sheet2]

Comment: I didn't understand the comparison between values in Sheet1 and Sheet2. You want it to compare value in A1(Sheet1) with value in A1(Sheet2), or it should search A1(Sheet2) value in A column in Sheet1?

Comment: It should search if there is a value in the colum A(sheet2) that is the same as A1(sheet1) and it should change the value of status(B1) to 0

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some test data in xls(x) file for easier testing.

Comment: i got it! i used this code: =VERT.ZOEKEN(BJ4;Blad2.A3:I535;2;0) 
(my excel is in dutch)

Answer (score 1):

In the *status* column (I assume it is "B" as you do not show), enter the formula:

`if(AND(Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!B2="End of Life"),0,1)`

I have assumed:

1. *Artikelcode* is in column A, *Vooraadstatus* is in column B - both in sheet1.
2. sku is in column A and status is in column B - both on sheet2.
3. When the condition is **not** met, that a 1 gets placed in the *status* column.

If these assumptions are incorrect, please specify.

With these assumptions, the formula  goes into sheet2, column B, and you can copy down.

You can also do with an array formula - specify this, if this is the case.